# Apache, Enable Mod, Update AllowOverride to all, service apache2 restart FAILS

Tags: apache-2.4

I've tried to enable a mod `mod_rewrite` using `a2enmod`.  I then updated `AllowOveride` in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` from `None` to `All`.

When I tried to restart Apache, I received:
I was unable to restart Apache `Job for apache2.service failed. See 'systemctl status apache2.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.`.

There are no journals, systemctl returned:
`● apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2016-08-06 21:51:18 BST; 8min ago
  Process: 30175 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/apache2 stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 20381 ExecReload=/etc/init.d/apache2 reload (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 31009 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)`

Any ideas what has gone wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This was a general, make sure you don't accidentally paste cr@p into your config files. I'd accidentally pasted in a path without realising, it wasn't correct syntax, so through a wobbly.

I tried `diff`, couldn't read the response as I'm not used to it, so **split my terminal and looked at the config file now and a backup from yesterday**, made it much easier.

**Moral of this post, backup, Backup, BACKUP!!!**

FYI, I do an Hourly, Daily, Weekly, Monthly backup of key config files on my system.  Has saved my bacon a number of times.